# Printing string in list of list (table)

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty amateur in python and currently I'm on opening files, reading it and printing the contents. Basically i want to print the content from a file into a table containing this:

```
South Africa:France
Spain:Chile
Italy:Serbia
```

Here's my code I've worked on:

```
fileName = input("Enter file name:")
openFile = open(fileName)
table = []

for contents in openFile:
    ListPrint = contents.split()
    table.append(ListPrint)
print(table)
```

after doing this i get what i want which is in table form where it consists of list of list. however, the thing I'm concerned of is the string 'South Africa' where it prints it like this:

```
['South','Africa:France']
```

is there any method where i could code python to provide me with:

```
['South Africa:France']
```

much appreciated for any help.

Comment: if you are pairing things together I'd recommend using dictionaries. But depending on how the file contents look it's hard to tell you how to handle it. If each line is a pair and they are separated by : I'd use that as the separator to split on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, scrap that list/list of list idea. You *want* a dictionary.
Second, you are splitting your string by whitespace but you need to split it by the : character.

```
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     countries = {}
...     for line in f:
...         first, second = line.strip().split(':')
...         countries[first] = second
... 
>>> countries
{'Italy': 'Serbia', 'Spain': 'Chile', 'South Africa': 'France'}
>>> countries['South Africa']
'France'
```

Answer (score 1):

[split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by delimiter `contents.split(":")`